# Google SaveToDrive code works only for localhost and does not respond for server/domain name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I am trying to add a saveto drive button to my website. Following sample code works if the url in the browser is typed as "localhost" and FAILS or nothing happens, no error when used with the server name or domain name.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Save to Drive of exported PDF: Async Load with Language</title>
        <link rel="canonical" href="http://global.com">
      </head>
      <body>
      File 1 Emp 5::
        <div class="g-savetodrive"
             data-src="./pdfGen.jsp?selEmp=5"
             data-filename="Emp5.pdf"
             data-sitename="Sample Application">
        </div>
<BR/><BR/>
      File 2 Emp 6::
        <div class="g-savetodrive"
             data-src="./pdfGen.jsp?selEmp=6"
             data-filename="Emp6.pdf"
             data-sitename="Sample Application">
        </div>
        

        <script type="text/javascript">
          window.___gcfg = {
            lang: 'en-US'
          };
        </script>
        <script>
window.onLoadCallback = function(){
  gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: "<CreatedApplication Key>.apps.googleusercontent.com"

    });
}
</script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Have created a project in google console, Created credentials clientkey, set the project to Testing/developer mode.
When accessed the application as "http://localhost:8180/Sample/gDrive.html" or "http://localhost:8180/Sample/gDrive.jsp",It's working fine. But,
"http://devsys.mtv.global.com:8180/Sample/gDrive.html", the buttons are rendered and on clicking that, no error is thrown, nothing happens.  Very disgusting.

Any help is appreciated. Thank

Answer (score 0):

### Be sure to add the Authorized JavaScript Origin

[image]

More information can be found here:

> https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow

Comment: The sites are added to whitelisting

Comment: Can you add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your original question, or at least more details/screenshots?